Nginx don't pass authorization to http-Login
I got some IPcams which i can call with http-authorization like
http://user:password@cam-url/snapshot.jpg
For reasons i need to proxy the http-cams with a ssl-nginx-reverse-proxy.
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name camproxy.my.home;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://camproxy.my.home;
        include proxy_params;
    }
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  listen [::]:443 ssl;
  server_name camproxy.my.home;

  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/my.home_ssl_certificate.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/_.my.home_private_key.key;

  location / {
        proxy_pass http://cam-url;
        include proxy_params;
        
      client_max_body_size 0;
      }
 }

proxy_params are
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;


This works as long as I leave the authorization deactivated.
When adding the usual
location / {
        proxy_pass http://cam-url;
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_set_header Authorization "Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
        

the cam-login-site ignores the login-values and asks for authorization as if I called the site without  user:password.
On one different cam it works perfektly this way.
The cam-webserver has an index.asp. Don't know how this makes a difference.
Are there any other methods to pass login-information in nginx-proxies?
I tried
        proxy_set_header Authorization $http_authorization;
        proxy_pass_header Authorization;

with the same results.
Any suggestions?
